# Multiple insert to related tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I would like to ask if anyone of you tried to insert multiple records at once in a related tables?
Here's the scenario. I have a table of Drug and DrugMovement. Now I want to insert records to both tables using from a xls file as source. So this xls file contains thousand of records. By the time the user upload that file. All content of that file will be inserted to the tables. Now I'm thinking of batch upload. But I have no idea what will be the best approach to this.

Below is the schema

======== Drug Table ==========

```
class Drug extends Model
{
    public function drugMovements() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\DrugMovement');
    }
}
```

======== Drug Movement ===========

```
class DrugMovement extends Model
{

    public function drug() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Drug');
    }
}
```

Now I want to save records to both this table with a thousand of records inserting at once. How can I achieve this?
If I do something like this then it will be a waste of resource as I need to loop to all the records and do thousands of insert.

```
foreach($datas as $data) {
  $drug = Drug::create([
        "pharmacy_id"     => 1,
        "name"            => $data->drug_name,
        "strength"        => $data->strength,
   ]);

  $drug_movements = new DrugMovement([
        "drug_id"         => $drug->id,
        "quantity"        => $data->quantity,
        "pharmacist_id"   => 1,
    ]);

  $drug->drugMovements()->save($drug_movements);
  $drug->save();
}
```

As you can see if data has thousands of records it will insert thousand times. How can I optimize this?

Comment: You can simply insert all the data at once using a single array for each table. So instead if inserting in the foreach just create the arrays you wish to insert, then do a `Drug::insert(array_goes_here)` and `DrugMovement::inesrt(array_goes_here)`.

Comment: That is not possible since I need the newly inserted Drug id on the Drugmovement table. This is the related field. So every entry on Drug table should have an equivalent entry on Drugmovement.

Comment: If there aren't any concurrent connections to the database, the id problem is easily fixed. Just get the last id of the drug before the foreach begins and assume that the inserted id will be last id + 1 for the first loop, last id + 2 for the second and so on.

Comment: well that wont do either as there are other user that might be using the same module and might uploading multiple items also. so having incrementing counter might not be the best aaproach

Comment: Since you're using laravel, I can safely assume you're using InnoDB as the engine. You could (and this is a judgement call think about it if it works for you do it, if not, don't) lock the table while doing the update and use my above mentioned suggestion. Pro: It will be a lot faster than inserting in a loop. Cons, no other inserts can be done while you do your insert.

Comment: Yup locking would be good but just like you said no insert  can be done while its lock. Assuming a user imported/inserted 100k or datas first then the second would just input 100 data. The problem is that the second user will have to wait for the 100k insert data to finish. I'm just looking for something that's like codeigniter insert_batch but with a twist of insert together with the related tables.

Comment: I'm not aware of any approach that could that, other than the one you mention in your question. Another, more...aaaa...creative approach would be to start from the maximum possible id and insert starting from there, but decrement the inserted id. Not the best idea, but given your situation, not the worst either.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to make two arrays and after that insert them to the database.

```
$latestDrugID = Drug::max('id'); 
// Of course if your database is empty start from `1`

foreach($datas as $data) {
    $drugs[] = [
        "pharmacy_id"     => 1,
        "name"            => $data->drug_name,
        "strength"        => $data->strength,
     ];

    $drug_movements[] = [
        "drug_id"         => $latestDrugID++,
        "quantity"        => $data->quantity,
        "pharmacist_id"   => 1,
    ];
}

Drug::insert($drugs);
DrugMovement::insert($drug_movements);
```

**PS:** You may want to chunk these arrays into little pieces depending on how large your data is.